# Pyspark: using filter for feature selection

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an array of dimensions 500 x 26. Using the filter operation in pyspark,  I'd like to pick out the columns which are listed in another array at row i. Ex: if
    `a[i]= [1 2 3]`

Then pick out columns 1, 2 and 3 and all rows. Can this be done with filter command?  If yes, can someone show an example or the syntax?

Comment: If i uderstand corectly you have rdd of arrays (500x26) but how is i connected to elements of your rdd.

Comment: It is not connected.. just an array element that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to filter columns, but not records. Fo doing this you need to use Spark's map function - to transform every row of your array represented as an RDD. See in my example:

```
# generate 13 x 10 array and creates rdd with 13 records, each record contains a list with 10 elements
rdd = sc.parallelize([range(10) for i in range(13)])

def make_selector(cols):
    """use closure to configure select_col function
    :param cols: list - contains columns' indexes to select from every record
    """
    def select_cols(record):
            return [record[c] for c in cols]
    return select_cols

s = make_selector([1,2])
s([0,1,2])
>>> [1, 2]

rdd.map(make_selector([0, 3, 9])).take(5)
```

results in

```
[[0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same answer as @vvladymyrov's, but without closures:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([range(10) for i in range(13)])
columns = [0,3,9]
rdd.map(lambda record: [record[c] for c in columns]).take(5)
```

results in

```
[[0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9], [0, 3, 9]]
```